# work with composer in php

Tags: php, laravel, cygwin, composer-php

hi I have a problem in adding `illuminate/html` to my laravel project in my `composer.json` file. I've added this code to `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
},
```

I think after doing this, I should execute:

```
composer update
```

in cygwin in the folder of my project. When I do this, I get this error:

```
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
```

please help me thanks.

Comment: Seems like a problem with your composer install.

Comment: You can run composer from a windows command window you know

Comment: @RiggsFolly no its not work too